# How to access the ID of the elements inside ViewChildren?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a series of mat-expansion-panels created from a ngFor loop.

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let num of countArray" [attr.id]="num + 'exp'" #expPanels>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
            {{num}}
        </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

I'm using ViewChildren to reference them in my .ts code because I'm trying to expand one of them.

```
  @ViewChildren("expPanels")
  expPanels :QueryList<MatExpansionPanel>;
```

The reason for that is because I'm trying to select one of them and expand it programmatically.

```
const selectedPanel = this.expPanels.find(e => e.id == '5exp');   
selectedPanel.expanded=true;
```

However selectedPanel is always null.

Looking inside this.expPanels, I can see the id isn't what I set in [attr.id], it is something like "cdk-accordion-child-300".

How can I filter by id or some other attribute in my ViewChildren's QueryList to get the panel I want to expand?

Comment: Have you tried only [id]?

Comment: yep. same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not found a clean solution because if i query the `ElementRef`, i was unable to access the `expanded` instance property of `MatExpansionPanel` and if i query the component instance, i was unable to access the dom element. So i queried both:

```
  @ViewChildren("expPanels", { read: ElementRef })
  expPanelElems: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  @ViewChildren("expPanels")
  expPanels: QueryList<MatExpansionPanel>;
```

and then used the dom elements to find the correct index and then use this index to toggle the right component instance.

```
  const selectedPanelIdx = this.expPanelElems
    .toArray()
    .findIndex(e => e.nativeElement.id === "5exp");
  this.expPanels.toArray()[selectedPanelIdx].expanded = true;
```

It works but i have to admit its not really clean. It would be simpler if you can lookup the index in your data array which is used inside `ngFor`:

```
const selectedPanelIdx = this.countArray.findIndex(n => n === 5)
```

Comment: but thanks for the `read: ElementRef`, I didn't know about that and it saved my life!